# Proper replacement of PreProcessInterceptor interface : RestEasy

Tags: authentication, resteasy, jboss-eap-7

In RestEasy 3.0.16.Final version PreProcessInterceptor interface is deprecated. So what is the proper replacement of this interface. In jboss eap 7 RestEasy version 3.0.16.Final is used.

Old code -

```
@Provider
@ServerInterceptor
@SecurityPrecedence
public class AbcInterceptor implements PreProcessInterceptor
{
 public ServerResponse preProcess(final HttpRequest httpRequest, ResourceMethod resourceMethod) throws Failure,
        WebApplicationException {
    // auth logic

}
}
```

New code -

```
@Provider
@ServerInterceptor
@SecurityPrecedence
public class AuthenticationInterceptor
{
 public ServerResponse preProcess(HttpRequest httpRequest, ResourceMethodInvoker method)
        throws Failure, WebApplicationException {
   // auth logic

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The **org.jboss.resteasy.spi.interception.PreProcessInterceptor** interface is replaced by the **javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter** interface in RESTEasy 3.x.

So, you can can use the ContainerRequestFilter for the same.